# Bash script: make sure files are written and accessible before continuing

Tags: bash, filesystems, cluster-computing

I am running a bash script which performs varied operations: reads in files, writes files, takes input from keyboard, executes external (non-bash) code, etc. I have noticed that even when using the same input the results are not always consistent. Very concisely, imagine if the following code (it's a lot more complicated in practice):

```
echo "1 2 3" > file
awk '{printf "%.2f\n", $1}' file
```

sometimes printed the correct result, which is `1.00`, and sometimes printed `0.00`. I believe this is happening because the files on the hard drive are not updated fast enough. I am running this script on a scientific cluster frontend, which does not always behave smoothly, i.e. sometimes lags when typing `ls` before printing directories, etc. (this is because of some d***heads running their Matlab scripts on it, but that's another story...).

My question is: how can I make sure that all files dynamically written by my script are available to that same script in their latest version? That is, I want to make sure that the command executed immediately after `echo "1 2 3" > file` will see that `file` effectively contains `1 2 3`, regardless of what it contained before of whether it existed at all.

Comment: Do you have any subprocess/anything running concurrently? I don't think your specific example is possible, with just the code you provided.

Comment: Nothing else running. I don't understand what you mean by "my specific example is not possible".

Comment: What kind of file system is the working directory where you run this? NFS? One of the cluster file systems? A distributed file system?

Comment: This behavior would break a lot of programs and generally doesn't happen. 

The more likely problems are:

1. Running the different steps on different threads or machines, or against different mount points. 
2. A bug in your code.

Comment: @twalberg: Our cluster manual says: "All compute nodes and front-end are connected to DDN SFA10k storage system: large disk arrays with the Lustre filesystem on top of it cross-mounted under /triton directory. The system provides about 430TB of disk space available to end-user." I don't know much about filesystems but could this "cross-mounted" thing be the reason?

Comment: @thatotherguy: I would almost completely rule out a bug, because the script gives the correct result most of the time, especially when the cluster's frontend is not lagging. Given that the codes is fully deterministic (no random numbers, etc.) any errors in the results should be consistent.

Comment: @Miguel Well, that's where I was headed with that - perhaps someone with some experience with Lustre could add more, but I was wondering if a file written on one node of the cluster does not show up immediately on other nodes due to replication, caching or other phenomena... I'm not particularly familiar with Lustre, though...

Answer (score -1):

By the time your bash script starts reading and processing files, it is already too late to ensure consistency.

I suggest some code changes to which whichever process or processes are writing the files that your bash script reads...

if for example the source process wrote everything to `file.tmp` and **only** when it was done, the very last thing it did was reaname(2) (http://linux.die.net/man/2/rename‎) it from `file.tmp` to `file.txt` -- then your bash script would know that file.txt is complete.

If the source processes log continuously, then they may want to consider log rotation (larger can of worms), and ensuring that your bash post-processing points only at rotated files, not the live one.